# vue.js http get web api url render list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-resource

I am using vue.js to http get from a web api a list of projects and render them in a list but currently the list is only rendering one items of the eight that response is returning in the array, please help! https://codepen.io/mruanova/pen/mprEap?editors=1111

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/0.12.7/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/0.1.13/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
{{projects}}
<ul>
  <li v-for="project in projects">PROJECT {{project.ProjectId}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            projects: []
        },
        ready: function () {
            var self = this;
            const url = "https://246gg84zg8.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/projects";
            this.$http.get(url).then(function (data) {
                console.log(JSON.parse(data.response).Items.length)
             console.log(JSON.parse(data.response).Items[0].ProjectId)
                self.$set('projects', JSON.parse(data.response).Items)
            })
        }
    })
</script>
```

current result:

[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

PROJECT

expected:

PROJECT 1
PROJECT 2
PROJECT 3
PROJECT 4
PROJECT 5
PROJECT 6
PROJECT 7
PROJECT 8

Comment: I see the problem, the data is not well formatted and VUE cannot read it: [ { "Website": "xxx", "Address": "xxx", "Position": "xxx", "ProjectId": 7, "Name": "xxx" },  BUT INSTEAD THE DATA SHOULD HAVE BEEN [ "Project": { "Website": "xxx", "Address": "xxx", "Position": "xxx", "ProjectId": 7, "Name": "xxx" },

Comment: Incorrect, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems here. First of all, you are using a *very* old version of Vue, which is inadvisable, to say the least. As soon as I cleaned up the codepen example you posted, pulled in a current version of Vue, and updated things to be more idiomatic, the basic concept of your code works just fine.

https://codepen.io/nickforddesign/pen/rpMLgV?editors=1011

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      projects: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    const url = 'https://246gg84zg8.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/projects';
    this.$http.get(url).then(data => {
      const items = JSON.parse(data.response).Items
      items.map(item => {
        // push to the projects array to make sure Vue's reactivity works
        this.projects.push(item)
      })
    })
  }
})
```